# JSR303's primitive and iterable primitive validator

Tags: java, validation, jsr330

Is it somehow possible to implement a custom validator which handles both `T` and `Iterable<T>` objects, where `T` is either primitive type or object?
The goal is to implement only a single ConstraintValidator object instead of two: `*ConstraintValidator` and `*ListConstraintValidator`
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can make T an `Object` and do some `instanceof` checks. But you can't handle primitive types. You have to go with the boxed versions.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to save code - no, it's not possible.